# Update "favorite" field for a project in Asana API

Tags: asana, asana-api

There's no documentation for updating the `favorite` field.

Currently I'm trying the following method:

```
PUT https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{projectid}
```

Post data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "favorite": true
  }
}
```

There's no error reported. The Asana API returns the project details as the response with the `responseCode` 200. But when I view the project in Asana the Favorite field has not been updated.

How do I use the API to modify this field?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this. The Asana app didn't reflect the changes right away. It took a few moments to show the project in the Favorite list.

If anyone else is looking into this undocumented feature please be aware when setting the favorite field to "1" or "0" (the representation in the the API) it returns the 400 responsecode. The value True or False must be processed and not in quotes.